# how to view ALL file properties in windows 7

Tags: file, properties-file

It is well known that exe/dll/sys files have properties such as "File Description", "Type", "File version" etc.
What is less known is that the programmer (which creates these files) can add properties as he wishes : for example "Comment_A", "Comment_B", etc.
So the question is : how to view ALL file properties in windows 7 ?

Here is how to view the properties (taken from Microsoft's site "View the properties for a file") :

- Open the folder that contains the file whose properties you want to see.
- Right-click the file whose properties you want to see, and then click Properties.
- Click the Details tab to see **all** the properties associated with this file.

But in-spite of the above documentation, NOT all properties are displayed (it does not display the properties such as "Comment_A" etc).
If you take the same file to a Windows XP system, then you can really see all files (including "Comment_A").

So we come back to the original question :  how to view **ALL** file properties in windows 7 ?

Thanks
zmau